# How do i generate a new array based on this condtiions? => given a salesman's name find all products that sold over 5000, sorted alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, object

I’m developing the backEnd part for a selling app in which I have **3 Array of Objects**, one got the sellers' name, the second one has the monthly sales, and the other has the products being sold. Based on this information I was told by my superiors to generate an Array  => with the *product's name*, *sorted from a to z*, *with *the condition that the product has exceeded 5000 units sold*, and that it has *been sold for a particular salesman* => **given a salesman's name find all products that sold over 5000, sorted alphabetically**.
These are the 3 Arrays:

```
const sellers = [
    {id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},
    {id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},
    {id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}
  ];
const products = [
    { id: 1, credencial: "132254524", name: "televisores" },
    { id: 2, credencial: "143618668", name: "estufas" },
    { id: 3, credencial: "78903228", name: "celulares" },
    { id: 4, credencial: "176812737", name: "Audio" },
    { id: 5, credencial: "216352696", name: "heladeras" },
  ];

const sales = [
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 1, quantity: 1200 },
  { productsId: 1, sellerId: 1, quantity: 500 },
  { productsId: 5, sellerId: 2, quantity: 20000 },
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 3, quantity: 8401 },
  { productsId: 3, sellerId: 1, quantity: 2877 },
  { productsId: 3, sellerId: 2, quantity: 1736 },
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 3, quantity: 2965 },
  { productsId: 4, sellerId: 4, quantity: 1651 },
  { productsId: 5, sellerId: 1, quantity: 700 },
  { productsId: 1, sellerId: 1, quantity: 7956 },
];
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const namesArray = sales.filter(e => e.productsId=== 3 & e.sellerId===3)
    const array= []
    namesArray.forEach(element => {
   const test= namesArray.filter(e => e.sellerId===element.id)
```

Don't take that lines of code too seriously, not proud of them, just wanted to show what I tried.
However, the end result should look like this:

```
const result= ['celulares', 'estufas' ]
```

Comment: by `that it has been sold for a particular salesman` do you mean given a salesman's name find all products that sold over 5000, sorted alphabetically?

Comment: That's correct!

Answer (score 0):

So from our comment it appears you want this logic:

> Given a sellers name, find all the products that sold 5000 or more and listen them alphabetically.

The first issue here is that your expected results contains `celulares` which does not appear to ever get over 5000 units sold.

Logically, the [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method was a good approach and on the right track. You can also [`array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to grab the first element that matches a condition.

```js
const sellers = [
    {id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},
    {id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},
    {id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}
  ];
const products = [
    { id: 1, credencial: "132254524", name: "televisores" },
    { id: 2, credencial: "143618668", name: "estufas" },
    { id: 3, credencial: "78903228", name: "celulares" },
    { id: 4, credencial: "176812737", name: "Audio" },
    { id: 5, credencial: "216352696", name: "heladeras" },
  ];

const sales = [
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 1, quantity: 1200 },
  { productsId: 1, sellerId: 1, quantity: 500 },
  { productsId: 5, sellerId: 2, quantity: 20000 },
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 3, quantity: 8401 },
  { productsId: 3, sellerId: 1, quantity: 2877 },
  { productsId: 3, sellerId: 2, quantity: 1736 },
  { productsId: 2, sellerId: 3, quantity: 2965 },
  { productsId: 4, sellerId: 4, quantity: 1651 },
  { productsId: 5, sellerId: 1, quantity: 700 },
  { productsId: 1, sellerId: 1, quantity: 7956 },
];


function findTopBySeller(seller) {
  const result = [];
  // Get the id of the seller
  const id = sellers.find(el => el.name === seller).id;
  // Filter the sales array to get all the items with >= 5000
  const filteredSalesArray = sales.filter(el => el.sellerId === id && el.quantity >= 5000);
  // now use the productIds to get the products into your results array
  products.forEach(product => {
    const found = filteredSalesArray.find(item => item.productsId === product.id);
    if (found) {
      result.push(product.name);
    }
  });
  // return the result using the <Array>.sort() method
  return result.sort();
}

console.log(findTopBySeller('juan'));
console.log(findTopBySeller('apolo'));
console.log(findTopBySeller('adrian'));
```

The last little bit uses the "out of the box" functionality of [`<Array>.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to get the final list alphabetically

If we go by the describe logic above, this will output results, however they differ from your expected results mentioned above. Also, the complexity of this algorithm is (at least) exponential, so it will be slow on large datasets.